# can not pass data to viewdidload, Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

i requested data from webserver by alamofire. i want to  pass data to viewdidload but data in viewdidload is empty, please help me explain. thanks and sory for my english. this my code

```
class LiveScoreViewController: UIViewController 
{
   var matchData : JSON! = []

func loadLiveScore(section: String){
    DNService.getLiveScore(section) { (JSON) -> () in
        self.matchData = JSON[ ]

        self.matchData = self.matchData["match"]
        //print(self.matchData) -> is ok
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadLiveScore("LiveScore")

    //print(self.matchData) -> is empty 

}}
```

Comment: Your view did load print statement will call first and then after some time response will come then only self.matchData have a data other wise it's empty

Answer (score 3):

If `DNService.getLiveScore` is a webservice call, then you wont be able to get the matchData inside viewDidLoad, since the webservice call will take some time to complete, whatever you are trying to do with the matchData should be done in the completion block of `DNService.getLiveScore` most likely

If you want, you can put a print statement right after `loadLiveScore` in `viewDidLoad` and also in the completion block, and you will see the order of execution of the print statements is not what you are expecting

Answer (score 1):

`getLiveScore` is asynchronous method. So you have to use completion handler to get the response. Make an handler for `loadLiveScore`

```
func loadLiveScore(section: String), handler: (JSON) -> ()) {

    DNService.getLiveScore(section) { (JSON) -> () in

        handler(JSON) 

    }
}
```

Call the method from your viewDidLoad as like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadLiveScore("LiveScore") { json in

        print(json) // parse JSON as you need

        self.matchData = json["match"]
    }
}}
```

Comment: if i print self.matchData outside of loadLiveScore("LiveScore") { handled in....}  , it's still empty .why?

Comment: Because before download competed print statement become executed but when you place it under the loadLiveScore method then after completing download execute print statement.

Comment: @shuuichiakai you are missing a fundamental understanding of Asynchronous programming, go have a look here and you will understand why. http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/6040-what-is-asynchronous-programming.html